# How can I populate an array with selected values from dropdown in Angular?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I'm trying to populate an array with all selected values from a mat-select dropdown. The goal is to create an input field for every selected value like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv01s.png)

I thought about calling a method every time I select a value, but I'm not really sure on what to do next...
This is what I have:

MyComponent.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Products" [formControl]="products" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let product of productsList">{{ product }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

MyComponent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'm-mycomponent',
  templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  products = new FormControl();
  productsList = ['Prod1', 'Prod2', 'Prod3', 'Prod4', 'Prod5', 'Prod6'];
  productsToReturn = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  fillProductsToReturn(product){
    if(!this.productsToReturn.includes(product)){
      this.productsToReturn.push(product);
    }
  }
}
```

How can I call a method in the html file and populate the productsToReturn array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify when you want to access the selected objects.

Its simple if you want to access it when the form is submitted, like on a click of a button. Then you can use `this.products.value` to get the selected options.

If you want it at the time of selection, then you can bind to `selectionChange()` event

```
<mat-select placeholder="Products" [formControl]="products" multiple (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event) >
```

then in ts file you can get the selected options

```
onSelectionChange(e){
    console.log(e.value); //or
    console.log(this.toppings.value);
}
```

Comment: Hi!
I've updated my question with an image with the intended goal... But I'm going to try what you said and give some feedback! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer led me to what I wanted! After trying with your solution I achieved what I wanted... I just had to change (selectionChange) to (onSelectionChange) and move it to the mat-option element. I'll post my solution...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this manually. Just bind the `value` property of the `mat-option` to the current `product` string and your `FormControl` will contain the array of selected options.

Template

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Products" [formControl]="products" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let product of productsList" [value]="product">{{ product }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And in your component you can access the selected options via `this.products.value`.

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-uvzicn?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)
>   is a minimal stackblitz with a working solution. The selected values
>   are directly displayed next to the `mat-select`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
That works if I want to show the selected values on the dropdown but what if I want to show them on a separate list? That's why I want the array... I'll update my question so there's no confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem...
I made the following changes based on [j4rey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4120474/j4rey)'s answer

MyComponent.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Products" [formControl]="products" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let product of productsList" [value]="product" (onSelectionChange)="onSelectionChange(product)">{{ product }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div class="row" *ngFor="let product of productsToReturn">
  <div class="col-4">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput disabled="disabled" [value]="product">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <mat-form-field class="prod-qty">
      <input matInput step="1" value="1" min="1" type="number">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

MyComponent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'm-mycomponent',
  templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  products = new FormControl();
  productsList = ['Prod1', 'Prod2', 'Prod3', 'Prod4', 'Prod5', 'Prod6'];
  productsToReturn = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  onSelectionChange(product: string) {

    if (!this.productsToReturn.includes(product)) {
      this.productsToReturn.push(product);
    } else {
      let index = this.productsToReturn.indexOf(product);
      this.productsToReturn.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}
```